# How can i catch a server error with async await in javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch, server-error

So i have a function that fetches data from my API. I set a limit to the requests and when the limit is reached, the server returns a 500 response. When testing in local development, the error is catched and the `showLimitReachedAlert` function for a popup is triggered. When running the setup with docker (+ nginx) the popup function is not triggered.

How can i modify this function to catch 500 response and trigger the function?

```
function searchByKeyword() {
  for (let x in networks) {
    let urlParameter = x;
    let network = networks[x];

    async function SearchKeywordForNetwork() {
      let url = `${base}/articles/${urlParameter}/${startDate.value}/${endDate.value}/${searchKeyword.value}`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const json = await response.json();
      network.value = json;
    }

    SearchKeywordForNetwork().catch(showLimitReachedAlert);
  }
}
```

Comment: So look at your dev tools's network tab: is there even a 500 error to catch? Because it's a good bet there isn't, and instead your docker+nginx setup is not doing the same thing that your plain local setup does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to do this. Tested both in the Docker and local version.

```
function getMostRecentNews() {
  for (let x in networks) {
    let urlParameter = x;
    let network = networks[x];

    async function getToday() {
      let url = `${base}/articles/${urlParameter}`;

      fetch(url)
        .then(async (response) => {
          const json = await response.json();
          network.value = json;

          // check for error response
          if (!response.ok) {
            // const error = (json && json.message) || json.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          showLimitReachedAlert();
        });
    }

    getToday();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, glad you got your question answered! Looks like you're using something very similar to Gregorio's answer (`!response.ok` instead of `response.status !== 500`) - it's considered good practice to upvote and mark useful answers as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), to thank the poster and create a useful reference for others that may encounter this issue.

Comment: Yup yup, already tried to do it, but didn't allow because i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to actually throw an error, if you want to catch it.
Also, note that fetch() does not throw any error if the response has a 500 status code. To implement what you want, you need to check the response, throw an error if you've got a 500, then catch the error. Here's an example:

```
function searchByKeyword() {
  for (let x in networks) {
    let urlParameter = x;
    let network = networks[x];

    async function SearchKeywordForNetwork() {
      let url = `${base}/articles/${urlParameter}/${startDate.value}/${endDate.value}/${searchKeyword.value}`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      if (response.status == 500) 
        throw new Error("Got a 500 status code");
      const json = await response.json();
      network.value = json;
    }

    try {
      await SearchKeywordForNetwork()
    } catch (error) {
      showLimitReachedAlert();
    }
  }
}
```

Only thing that I would add: fetch throws an error if there is a network failure. It could be convenient to throw a custom error and check for the error's type in the catch statement. Otherwise, you'd call the showLimitReachedAlert in both cases.